# I am having a problem with textboxes in window's forms feature in c++

Tags: c++, windows, forms, textbox

Im pretty new to c++ and im building a calculator with the windows forms feature. I have made the UI and the UI consists of the user entering digits into the 2 text boxes and after that then the 2 numbers will be added together but I am having this problem and here is the code

```
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int ^ FirstNumber = textbox1->Text;
        int ^ SecondNumber = textBox3->Text;
        int ^ Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }
```

Here are my Errors:
[image: Errors]

Does anyone know a fix?? I am also having an error when I add the two var's together.

Comment: Well, the first error is difficult, because you've not provided a [mre]. The second is easy; you can't assign `Text` to an `int` variable.

Comment: Well, `textbox1->text` is a string, even if you've typed a number into it.  To convert it to a number, you have to use one of the numeric conversion methods.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive.  Notice that, in one of your lines of code you called it `textbox`, but in the other line of code you called it `textBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the Textbox strings to ints also you probably dont want managed pointers to those values. Something like this should work (untested):

```cpp
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        int FirstNumber =  System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox1->Text);
        int SecondNumber = System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
        int Result = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }
```

Edit: As @Robert Harvey pointed out in the comments, the first error is likely because `textbox1` likely should have been `textBox1` but without seeing the rest of the class code its difficult to say